# hide /show content in table while loop

Tags: javascript, php

[here is the image of the output of the code given below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v96CE.png)
The code below displays a table with hide/show content.

i want to display the username below the "username" heading of the table and the content that appears on clicking the "+" button should appear below their respective headers like project_name should appear under PROJECT NAME,project_id should appear under PROJECT ID and so on...

if anyone could help...

```
    <?php
$hostname_ckumbh = "localhost";
$database_ckumbh = "pmb_demo";
$username_ckumbh = "root";
$password_ckumbh = "";

$ckumbh = mysql_pconnect($hostname_ckumbh , $username_ckumbh , $password_ckumbh) or trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR);
mysql_select_db($database_ckumbh , $ckumbh); 


?>
<html>
<head>

<style>
.button1 {
    width: 100%
}.wid25{width:25% !important;float:left}

.sign_cls {
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 10%;
    background: #09F;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #FFF
}
.sign_cls2 {
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 10%;
    background: #900;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #FFF
}
.sign_cls,.sign_cls2 {float: left;  width: 1% !important;}
.date_cls {
    width: 90%;
}
.wid_25 {
    width: 25%;
    float: left;
    margin: 10px 0
}
.line_style td {
    width: 25%
}
</style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
function toggle(cls,cls2){
    if($("."+cls).is(":visible")){
        $("."+cls).hide("slow");    
        $("#"+cls2).removeClass('sign_cls2').addClass('sign_cls');      
    }else{
        $("."+cls).show("slow");
        $("#"+cls2).removeClass('sign_cls').addClass('sign_cls2');
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<table border="0%" align="center" width="100%" height="100%" >
        <tr class="line_style" align="center">
            </br>
          <td>User Name</td>
          <td>Project Name</td>
          <td>Project ID</td>
          <td>Task Details</td>
          <td>Status</td>
        </tr>
        <?php


    $record =mysql_query("SELECT `u_vemail` FROM `proj_user`");
    $i = 0;
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($record))
    {

    $record2 =mysql_query("SELECT `project_name` , `project_id` , `task_details` , `date` , `status` FROM  `add_tasks` WHERE   `user_name`='$row[u_vemail]'");



    ?>

        <tr align="center">      
        <td colspan="4">                
            <div class="button1" onClick="toggle('hide<?php echo $i;?>','test<?php echo $i;?>')" style="float:left">
         <span id="test<?php echo $i;?>" class="sign_cls">+</span><span class="date_cls"><?php echo $row["u_vemail"] ?></span>


         </div>  

         <div class="hide<?php echo $i;?>" style="display:none;width:100%;float:left;">            
        <?php

            while($row2 =mysql_fetch_array($record2))
        {   


        ?>                                
                    <div style="width:100%">


                        <div class="wid_25"><?php echo $row2["project_name"]; ?></div>
                        <div class="wid_25"><?php echo $row2["project_id"]; ?></div>
                        <div class="wid_25"><?php echo $row2["task_details"]; ?></div>
                        <div class="wid_25"><?php echo $row2["status"]; ?></div>                
                    </div>
        <?php 
        }
        ?></div>                    
        </td>                   
        </tr><?php
        $i++;
    }
        ?>        <table>
        </table>
          </td>

          </tr>

      </table>
      <br/>
      <br/>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just an initial question: can you see everything showing up on your screen?  It sounds like you've got everything working and are just looking for a way to implement this show/hide function.  Also, it looks like you've already attempted this with your toggle function although I'm not entirely sure where your variables cls and cls2 are coming from...

I tried something similar to get certain components to fade onto the screen with Javascript and CSS and what worked best for me what to add styling to the individual rows of a table and then apply a new style with javascript (i.e. make the style hidden and change it to visible with JS)

Here is what I mean...

```
#tableRow1 {opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 4s;
    -webkit-transition: 4s;
    transition-delay: 1s;
    -webkit-transition-delay: 1s;}
#tableRow2 {opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 4s;
    -webkit-transition: 4s;
    transition-delay: 1s;
    -webkit-transition-delay: 1s;}
#tableRow3 {opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 4s;
    -webkit-transition: 4s;
    transition-delay: 1s;
    -webkit-transition-delay: 1s;}


<tr id='tableRow2' width="0%">
<tr id='tableRow2' width="0%">
<tr id='tableRow2' width="0%">
```

And the JS:

```
function loadPage(){
    document.getElementById("tableRow1").style.opacity = 1;
    document.getElementById("tableRow2").style.opacity = 1;
    document.getElementById("tableRow3").style.opacity = 1;
}
```

I used opacity, but the concept would be the same for hidden.  You can call the JS function with your button and if you are creating multiple buttons, you can give each button a unique id with a loop and put a loop in the function so that it makes the appropriate row visible.  This should also work with div tags as long as they have a unique id.  Hopefully this helps...

Answer (score 0):

To appear username below username, Project name below project name you can try this code:

```
   <tr class="line_style" align="center">
      <th>User Name</th>
      <th>Project Name</th>
      <th>Project ID</th>
      <th>Task Details</th>
      <th>Status</th>
    </tr>

    <tr align="center">      
      <td colspan="4">                
        <div class="button1" onClick="toggle('hide<?php echo $i;?>','test<?php echo $i;?>')" style="float:left">
     <span id="test<?php echo $i;?>" class="sign_cls">+</span><span class="date_cls"><?php echo $row["u_vemail"] ?></span>

         </div>  

         <div class="hide<?php echo $i;?>" style="display:none;width:100%;float:left;">            
        <?php

           while($row2 =mysql_fetch_array($record2))
         {   
         ?>                                
           <div style="width:100%">


            <div class="wid_25"><?php echo $row2["project_name"]; ?></div>
            <div class="wid_25"><?php echo $row2["project_id"]; ?></div>
            <div class="wid_25"><?php echo $row2["task_details"]; ?></div>
            <div class="wid_25"><?php echo $row2["status"]; ?></div>                
            </div>
       <?php 
        }
        ?>
            </div>                    
       </td>                   
    </tr>


    The problem is you used (<td></td>) instead of (<th></th>) tag.
```

Comment: it made no difference ...bt thanks for the suggestion..wat i want exactly is initially all the email id should appear under the column "Username" in the table..and when "+" is clicked it should display the content below "Project Name","Project_ id" and so on

Comment: Thanks for the help evryone..but i juz added a blank div and applied some css and also changed the td colspan to 5 as i needed 5 columns in the table

Answer (score 0):

Hope it will help you........

```
<?php
$hostname_ckumbh = "localhost";
$database_ckumbh = "pmb_demo";
$username_ckumbh = "root";
$password_ckumbh = "";

$ckumbh = mysql_pconnect($hostname_ckumbh, $username_ckumbh, $password_ckumbh) or trigger_error(mysql_error(), E_USER_ERROR);
mysql_select_db($database_ckumbh, $ckumbh);
?>
<html>
    <head>

        <style>
            .button1 {
                width: 100%
            }.wid25{width:25% !important;float:left}

            .sign_cls {
                cursor: pointer;
                width: 10%;
                background: #09F;
                font-weight: bold;
                color: #FFF
            }
            .sign_cls2 {
                cursor: pointer;
                width: 10%;
                background: #900;
                font-weight: bold;
                color: #FFF
            }
            .sign_cls,.sign_cls2 {float: left;  width: 1% !important;}
            .date_cls {
                width: 90%;
            }
            .wid_25 {
                width: 25%;
                float: left;
                margin: 10px 0
            }
            .line_style td {
                width: 25%
            }
        </style>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>


        <script type="text/javascript">
            function toggle(cls, cls2) {
                if ($("." + cls).is(":visible")) {
                    $("." + cls).hide("slow");
                    $("#" + cls2).removeClass('sign_cls2').addClass('sign_cls');
                } else {
                    $("." + cls).show("slow");
                    $("#" + cls2).removeClass('sign_cls').addClass('sign_cls2');
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table border="1"  align="center" width="100%" height="100%" >
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>User Name</td>
                <td>Project Name</td>
                <td>Project ID</td>
                <td>Task Details</td>
                <td>Status</td>
            </tr>
            <?php
                $record =mysql_query("SELECT `u_vemail` FROM `proj_user`");
                //$record = array('0', '1');  // push your sql result to this array
                $i = 0;
                while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($record)) {
                    //$row2 = array("project_name", "project_id", "task_details", "status");  // push your sql result to this array
                    $record2 =mysql_query("SELECT `project_name` , `project_id` , `task_details` , `date` , `status` FROM  `add_tasks` WHERE   `user_name`='$row[u_vemail]'");
                    $row2 =mysql_fetch_array($record2);
            ?>
                <tr align="center">
                    <td><span onclick="hideRow('ex<?php echo $i?>','id<?php echo $i?>')" id="id<?php echo $i?>">+</span></td>
                    <td class="ex<?php echo $i?>"><?php echo $row["u_vemail"] ?></td>            
                    <td class="ex<?php echo $i?>"><?php echo $row2["project_name"]; ?></td>                              
                    <td class="ex<?php echo $i?>"><?php echo $row2["project_id"]; ?></td>
                    <td class="ex<?php echo $i?>"><?php echo $row2["task_details"]; ?></td>
                    <td class="ex<?php echo $i?>"><?php echo $row2["status"]; ?></td>
                </tr>
            <?php
                    $i++;
                }
            ?>
        </table>
        <script>
            function  hideRow(id1,id2){
                $("."+id1).toggle();
                if(document.getElementsByClassName(id1)[0].style.display == 'none'){
                    $("#"+id2).css("background-color","red");
                }else{
                    $("#"+id2).css("background-color","white");
                }
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: can u provide dummy values in array so that i can try,, run query and give some dummy data.